# Windows Impersonation Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, asp.net-web-api

Hi guys i'm having a hard time to figure out why the Impersonation in WindowsIdentity does not work.

I will present the idea and also the code in the following.

So the idea is that i need to access within my application another application API.

```
public async Task<UserHrtbProfileDTO> HasHrtbAccessAsync(int userId, string systemUser)
        {
            WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            using (identity.Impersonate())
            {
                using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
                {
                    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true
                })
                {
                    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, true))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        string requestURI = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HRTB:Profile_Url"], userId);
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestURI);

                        return response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.OriginalString.Contains(requestURI)
                             ? new UserHrtbProfileDTO
                             {
                                 HrtbProfileUrl = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HRTB:Profile_Url"], userId),
                                 ResponseURI = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
                             }
                             : new UserHrtbProfileDTO
                             {
                                 ResponseURI = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri,
                                 RequestURI = requestURI,
                                 HasHrtbAccess = false,
                                 IdentityUserName = identity.Name + "\n" + identity.IsAuthenticated + "\n" + identity.AuthenticationType + "\n" + identity.ImpersonationLevel + "\n"
                             };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If i'm running on local IIS the behavior is OK, i have access where i need to have and the access is being denied where i don't have it. The API response for which the request is made returns the response that i expect.

But when i deploy and run from a server the response is different thus the behavior is not as it should. 
I'm guessing that the request is not emitted from the perspective of the user that has made it.

Any idea ,suggestions, or a different approach in which i can solve the issue. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked enabling impersonation from web.config file and set the IIS application pool to classic managed pipeline.

If you have any other knowledge of other solutions, please share. 
Thank you